# google sheets email script not runnable by all shared people

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sharing

I have a google sheet shared with other people (I'm the owner) and in it there is a button linked to a corresponding bundle script that send me an email when the user logged press that button (so if I click the button I send an email to me).

All the other people have the "edit" privileges but when they click the button an error occurs saying that it's impossible to send the mail (when I click all works perfectly).

The accounts associated to the other people has the same email domain of mine (**not gmail**, but related to the same company).

It seems like that the script has different privileges because I have no problem, while the other people do.

As normal, at the first time they click to the button they (but also me) had to accept the google authorization to "send email as you" (as the avatar of the current account logged).

This is the code of the button:

'''

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sel = sheet.getSelection();
  var sel_range = sel.getActiveRange();  
  var message = sel_range.getValues();

  // get task IDs
  var prev_values = sel.getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.PREVIOUS).getValues(); 
  var cod_tickets = [];
  for (var k in prev_values){
    cod_tickets.push(prev_values[k][0]);
  } 

  var emailAddress = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Manager').getRange('I2').getValue();
  var subject = 'ticket ' + cod_tickets;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

'''
I say that they send an email to me, because the "emailAddress" variables will be filled with the value of the cell that contains my email address.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work then they press a button second time after granting auth on first press?

Comment: What if you transferred ownership to one of them? Would it send then?    It could also have to do with security settings at your company... or as @roma said, they might just need to click it again.

Comment: I know to click two times after granting authorization: the error appears after two clicks

Comment: Now I have discovered that another colleague that is working at home (as me) with VPN use the sheet without error (while the others colleagues that have presented the error are all working in the factory), so in my opinion it's no a problem of privileges. I have asked to the IT group of the company and they said me that there are no firewall restriction that could present the error.

Answer (score 0):

### Have a look at the documentation for [restrictions for simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
>   simple trigger **cannot send an email** because the Gmail service
>   requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase
>   with the Language service, which is anonymous.

**Solution:**

Use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead.

- Go to `Edit->Current Project's trigger`
- Click on `+Add trigger`
- `Select event type` `On edit`.

Your function should no be named `onEdit`, because otherwise both the simple and installable trigger would fire at once which can lead to problems.

**The problem:**

The installable trigger will fire for every user, but it will fire on your behalf, so the email will always be you.

If this is a problem, you will need to use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) that will [impersonate](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation) the session user, which will make things more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have discovered (as indicated in the comment of my question) that an other my collegue is able to use the sheet without errors (but in VPN), so I assume that there are no problem related to the user privilges, are you agree with me?

Comment: What do you mean by use the sheet? Do you mean get the script to run correctly and send an email? I am correct that you are not running the script automatically `onEdit` but rather run it manually by clicking on a button to which it is bound? This changes the issue.

Comment: You said that the users with whom you share the sheet do not have a gmail address but have the same email domain like you? Are you talking about a GSuite domain or another provider? Are the users signed it with multiple accounts into their browser session? This is a common reason for failure, make sure that the users asign out of all their sessions with the exception of the account with which you shared the sheet (and it needs to be a gmail/GSuite account!).

Comment: Yes, I mean get the script to run correclty and send an email. Yes, I have a button to run it manually (as said in the question).
My collagues have an email with a company domain under a gsuite account. I'm going to inform me about the multiple accounts. Thanks!